# How do you apply a ValueConverter to a convention-based Caliburn.Micro binding?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, binding, caliburn.micro, valueconverter

How do you apply a ValueConverter to a convention-based Caliburn.Micro binding? or do you need to use the {Binding} syntax?

I know I could do this

```
<TextBlock
    Text="{Binding Foo, Converter=fooToBarConverter}" />
```

but how do I apply that custom converter if I am using Caliburn.Micro's convention over configuration, like

```
<TextBlock
    x:Name="Foo" />
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to replace the ConventionManager.ApplyValueConverter func. By default it only does athe bool => Visibility conversion. Also, you can replace the ApplyStringFormat func for conventional string formatting. Have a look in the ConventionManager to see how it works.

Comment: Cool - thanks. I'd seen the SetBinding called this, but hadn't joined the dots in terms of needing to write my own...

Comment: So, presumably I'd want to store the default boolToVis func somewhere, create my own ApplyValueConverter, then restore the default one after the VM completes binding to the View. Is that a reasonable approach? Not sure I'd want to leave my very specific IVC lying around as the default, tbh...