# How do you apply a ValueConverter to a convention-based Caliburn.Micro binding Example?

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, windows-phone-8, caliburn.micro

I have seen the following question: [how-do-you-apply-a-valueconverter-to-a-convention-based-caliburn-micro-binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6581674/how-do-you-apply-a-valueconverter-to-a-convention-based-caliburn-micro-binding).

I couldn't post a comment on that topic, so I am posting my question here.

How to use the [`ConventionManager.ApplyValueConverter`](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Caliburn.Micro.Platform/ConventionManager.cs) in Caliburn.Micro for value converters when using convention based binding ?

Could anyone write an example here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ApplyValueConverter` is defined as a static `Func<>` delegate in the `ConventionManager` class.

In order to provide your own converter in convention-binding scenarios, you need to define your own `Func<>` in the `Configure()` method of your bootstrapper, something like this:

**NOTE:** I am assuming the conversion is from `string` to `Opacity`.

```
public class AppBootstrapper : Bootstrapper<ShellViewModel> {

    private static IValueConverter StringToOpacityConverter = new StringToOpacityConverter();

    public override void Configure() {

        var oldApplyConverterFunc = ConventionManager.ApplyValueConverter;

        ConventionManager.ApplyValueConverter = (binding, bindableProperty, property) => {
            if (bindableProperty == UIElement.Opacity && typeof(string).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType))
            //                                ^^^^^^^           ^^^^^^
            //                             Property in XAML     Property in view-model
                binding.Converter = StringToOpacityConverter;
                //                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                //                 Our converter used here.

            // else we use the default converter
            else
                oldApplyConverterFunc(binding, bindableProperty, property);

        };
    }

}
```

Comment: Wow, you know I've been using it for a fair while and I didn't even realise there was a convention for value converters! This saves a hell of a lot of typing!

Comment: @Charleh The funny thing is that I didn't know before the OP asked :). I am happy I learned that too.

Comment: It's the ONE thing I hate but never thought to check if there was support for.... (most) converters are so little bang for your buck when it comes to the amount of typing vs the payoff!